# key was not found in dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

The following exception, seems to suggest that one of the configuration values cannot be found:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "One or more errors occurred.",
            "type": "System.AggregateException",
            "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1.<InvokeWithRetryAsync>d__24`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.Client.ServiceRemotingPartitionClient.<InvokeAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.<InvokeAsyncV2>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.<ContinueWith>d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Sales.o777.OrderManagement.Controller.OrderCapturesController.<Post>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\\ws\\CleanRoom\\DEV\\Source\\ENTERPRISEAPI\\abc.API.Sales.o777.OrderManagement\\Sales.o777.OrderManagement\\Controller\\OrderCaptureController.cs:line 75\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
            "internalexception": {
                "message": "The given key was not present in the dictionary.",
                "type": "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException",
                "stacktrace": "   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)\r\n   at OCLineItemsActor.Interfaces.IOCLineItemsActor_.actor.disp.IOCLineItemsActorMethodDispatcher.OnDispatchAsync(Int32 , Object , IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody , IServiceRemotingMessageBodyFactory , CancellationToken )\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorManager.ActorMethodDispatch(ActorMethodDispatcherBase methodDispatcher, ActorBase actor, Int32 interfaceId, Int32 methodId, IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody requestBody, IServiceRemotingMessageBodyFactory remotingMessageBodyFactory, CancellationToken innerCancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorManager.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<InvokeAsync>b__0(ActorBase actor, CancellationToken innerCancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorManager.<DispatchToActorConcurrencyLockHeldAsync>d__48`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorManager.<DispatchToActorAsync>d__29`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorManager.<DispatchToActorAsync>d__29`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime.ServiceRemotingCancellationHelper.<Dispatabcequest>d__5`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Remoting.V2.Runtime.ActorServiceRemotingDispatcher.<HandleActorMethodDispatchAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.FabricTransport.Runtime.FabricTransportMessageHandler.<RequestResponseAsync>d__7.MoveNext()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The flow:

1. post a body against a microservice
2. that microservice kicks off an orchestration, and one of them is making use of methods on a shared interface `IOCLineItemsActor`

according to the following, the exception occurs at line 75, as seen in the innerexception:

`...\Sales.o777.OrderManagement\\Controller\\OrderCaptureController.cs:line 75\r\n--- End of stack trace from pr...`

and line 74/75 is the following:

```
var proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IOCLineItemsActor>(ActorId.CreateRandom(), new Uri(@"fabric:/abc.API/OCLineItemsActor/OCLineItemsActorService"));

await proxy.MergeLineItemsToOpportunity(orderCapture.Id, (Guid)orderCapture.OpportunityId); //this is line 75 ! seems like it may be looking for a onfig setting here?
```

When publishing the dev environment, we do not get the *given key was not present in dictionary* exception; however, when i publish to QA, then we DO get this exception.

i've compared the ApplicationParameters files (dev vs qa), and they are the same.

**what am i doing wrong? how do i figure out which key it is missing?**

here is `MergeLineItemsToOpportunity`

```
    internal class OCLineItemsActor : Actor, IOCLineItemsActor
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of OCLineItemsActor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actorService">
        ///     The Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorService that will host this ocLineItemsActor
        ///     instance.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="actorId">The Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.ActorId for this ocLineItemsActor instance.</param>
        public OCLineItemsActor(ActorService actorService, ActorId actorId)
            : base(actorService, actorId)
        {
            CMConnectionString = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")
                .Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CMDatabaseConnection"].Value;
            CRMConnectionString = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")
                .Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMDatabaseConnection"].Value;
            SprocExecutor = new SprocExecutor(CMConnectionString, CRMConnectionString);
        }

    public Task MergeLineItemsToOpportunity(int orderCaptureId, Guid opportunityId)
    {
        OCLineItemsEventSource.Current.Message("orderCaptureId: " + orderCaptureId);

        var executor = new SprocExecutor(CMConnectionString, CRMConnectionString);

        SprocExecutor.MergeLineItemsToOpportunity(orderCaptureId, opportunityId);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}
```

Comment: Woah i just seen all your badges. however i think we are missing some vital information. i mean whats inside`MergeLineItemsToOpportunity` as this cant be the end of the story

Comment: thanks @TheGeneral i've updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than directly referencing the `Interfaces` DLL, I referenced the `csproj` file that houses the interfaces. Why that worked I have no clue.